# Does a description of the original design for the Great Seal of the United States by Simitiere survive?

Tags: united-states, heraldry

[*The Great Seal of the United States by U.S. Department of State, Bureau of Public Affairs*](https://www.state.gov/documents/organization/135450.pdf) contains details as to Pierre Eugene du Simitiere's role in designing the Great Seal of the United States

> Finally they sought the help of a talented “drawer” and portrait
>   artist, Pierre Eugene du Simitiere. To the post of consultant, Du
>   Simitiere brought some knowledge of heraldry—the art of describing
>   coats of arms—and also experience in designing seals.

The center of the [original proposed design for the Great Seal of the United States by Pierre Eugene du Simitiere in 1776](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:SealOfTheUS_Prototype.png) appears to depict a heraldic shield which includes a [Lion (heraldry)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lion_(heraldry)), a [Fleur-de-lis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fleur-de-lis), and a [Double-headed eagle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-headed_eagle), though this observation is not possible to verify based on the linked document, as there is no description within the document for the original proposed drawing.

Did Pierre Eugene du Simitiere specifically publish, leave in his notes and journals; or, do other primary source records exist of, a description the original proposed design of the Great Seal of the United States?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The description of du Simitiere's initial design for the Great Seal is included on [the Great Seal](http://greatseal.com/committees/firstcomm/) website:

> "The shield has six Quarters... pointing out the Countries from which
>   these States have been peopled."
>
> Three British: 
>       Rose for England, Thistle for Scotland, Harp for Ireland
>
> Three European: 
>       Fleur-de-lis for France, Belgic Lion for Holland, 
>       Imperial Eagle for Germany
>
> The shield is bordered with the initials for "each of the thirteen
>   independent States of America."
>
> Crest: "The Eye of Providence in a radiant Triangle whose Glory
>   extends over the Shield and beyond the Figures."
>
> Motto: "E PLURIBUS UNUM"

together with an image showing Du Simitière's original (and restored) sketch.

---

That description is taken verbatim from papers submitted to the Continental Congress, and which were included in an off-print published by the Library of Congress titled [Some papers laid before the Continental Congress, 1775-](https://archive.org/stream/somepaperslaidbe00unit#page/56/mode/2up) in 1805. The text appears on pages 56-57.